# Need Assistance Fixing A Loop

Tags: rpa, workfusion

I have a script that needs to be altered so that it can copy certain info from a spreadsheet and save a new copy using the info copied as its name. This process also needs to be looped.

The pictures here show the parts intended to copy the info which works fine.
[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBuUx.png)

In the next pictures, it shows the parts intended to paste the info and save the file, however, it pastes all information instead of pasting the respective information according to each time the script is being saved.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDiRx.png)

An error like this appears:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vntlC.png)

The order in which the information is pasted and the extraction of information is correct, I just need to loop the pasting correctly.

This is a zip folder of my RPA script:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15s7J7XRhxDCxLhc8zx8IUm8x2twwsvNg

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is the file name is too long.

Comment: Hi, the file path is correct, it's just pasting all the information instead of respective top each step